# How to Correctly Cancel a TPL Task with Continuation

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, continuations, cancellation, request-cancelling

I have a long running operation which I am putting on a background thread using TPL. What I have currently works but I am confused over where I should be handling my `AggregateException` during a cancellation request.

In a button click event I start my process:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Utils.ShowWaitCursor();
    buttonCancel.Enabled = buttonCancel.Visible = true;
    try
    {
        // Thread cancellation.
        cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        token = cancelSource.Token;

        // Get the database names.
        string strDbA = textBox1.Text;
        string strDbB = textBox2.Text;

        // Start duplication on seperate thread.
        asyncDupSqlProcs =
            new Task<bool>(state =>
                UtilsDB.DuplicateSqlProcsFrom(token, mainForm.mainConnection, strDbA, strDbB),
                "Duplicating SQL Proceedures");
        asyncDupSqlProcs.Start();

        //TaskScheduler uiThread = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        asyncDupSqlProcs.ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                switch (task.Status)
                {
                    // Handle any exceptions to prevent UnobservedTaskException.             
                    case TaskStatus.Faulted:
                        Utils.ShowDefaultCursor();
                        break;
                    case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
                        if (asyncDupSqlProcs.Result)
                        {
                            Utils.ShowDefaultCursor();
                            Utils.InfoMsg(String.Format(
                                "SQL stored procedures and functions successfully copied from '{0}' to '{1}'.",
                                strDbA, strDbB));
                        }
                        break;
                    case TaskStatus.Canceled:
                        Utils.ShowDefaultCursor();
                        Utils.InfoMsg("Copy cancelled at users request.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Utils.ShowDefaultCursor();
                        break;
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); // Or uiThread.

        return;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

In the method `DuplicateSqlProcsFrom(CancellationToken _token, SqlConnection masterConn, string _strDatabaseA, string _strDatabaseB, bool _bCopyStoredProcs = true, bool _bCopyFuncs = true)` I have

```
DuplicateSqlProcsFrom(CancellationToken _token, SqlConnection masterConn, string _strDatabaseA, string _strDatabaseB, bool _bCopyStoredProcs = true, bool _bCopyFuncs = true)
{ 
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < someSmallInt; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < someBigInt; j++)
            {
                // Some cool stuff...
            }

            if (_token.IsCancellationRequested)
                _token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }
    catch (AggregateException aggEx)
    {
        if (aggEx.InnerException is OperationCanceledException)
            Utils.InfoMsg("Copy operation cancelled at users request.");
        return false;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Utils.InfoMsg("Copy operation cancelled at users request.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

In a button Click event (or using a `delegate` (buttonCancel.Click += delegate { /*Cancel the Task*/ }`) I cancel the`Task` as follows:

```
private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        cancelSource.Cancel();
        asyncDupSqlProcs.Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException aggEx)
    {
        if (aggEx.InnerException is OperationCanceledException)
            Utils.InfoMsg("Copy cancelled at users request.");
    }
}
```

This catches the `OperationCanceledException` fine in method `DuplicateSqlProcsFrom` and prints my message, but in the call-back provided by the `asyncDupSqlProcs.ContinueWith(task => { ... });` above the `task.Status` is always `RanToCompletion`; it should be cancelled!

What is the right way to capture and deal with the `Cancel()` task in this case. I know how this is done in the simple cases shown in [this example from the CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152765/Task-Parallel-Library-1-of-n#handlingExceptions) and from the [examples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607.aspx) but I am confused in this case when running a continuation.

How do I capture the cancel task in this case and how to ensure the `task.Status` is dealt with properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're catching the `OperationCanceledException` in your `DuplicateSqlProcsFrom` method, which prevents its `Task` from ever seeing it and accordingly setting its status to `Canceled`. Because the exception is handled, `DuplicateSqlProcsFrom` finishes without throwing any exceptions and its corresponding task finishes in the `RanToCompletion` state.

`DuplicateSqlProcsFrom` shouldn't be catching either `OperationCanceledException` or `AggregateException`, unless it's waiting on subtasks of its own. Any exceptions thrown (including `OperationCanceledException`) should be left uncaught to propagate to the continuation task. In your continuation's `switch` statement, you should be checking `task.Exception` in the `Faulted` case and handling `Canceled` in the appropriate case as well.

In your continuation lambda, `task.Exception` will be an `AggregateException`, which has some handy methods for determining what the root cause of an error was, and handling it. Check the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx) particularly for the `InnerExceptions` (note the "S"), `GetBaseException`, `Flatten` and `Handle` members.

---

**EDIT**: on getting a `TaskStatus` of `Faulted` instead of `Canceled`.

On the line where you construct your `asyncDupSqlProcs` task, use a `Task` constructor which accepts both your `DuplicateSqlProcsFrom` delegate and the `CancellationToken`. That associates your token with the task.

When you call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` on the token in `DuplicateSqlProcsFrom`, the `OperationCanceledException` that is thrown contains a reference to the token that was cancelled. When the Task catches the exception, it compares that reference to the `CancellationToken` associated with it. If they match, then the task transitions to `Canceled`. If they don't, the Task infrastructure has been written to assume that this is an unforeseen bug, and the task transitions to `Faulted` instead.

[Task Cancellation in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this. It has really helped. I had gotten to the stage of removing the handeling from the `DuplicateSqlProcsFrom` method, but was still trying to capture it elsewhere.

Comment: I have done as you suggest, but in my continuation method i only ever get the `TaskStatus.Faulted` condition, never `TaskStatus.Cancelled`. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: I've added an explanation and the solution for this behaviour to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sacha Barber has great series of articles about TPL. Try this [one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152765/Task-Parallel-Library-1-of-n), he describe simple task with continuation and canceling

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This is the link I have provided. Although he cover cancellation of tasks it is not in the more complex scenario I have here - hence is no use to me. Thanks for your time.