# OperationCancelled Exception not being caught

Tags: razor, blazor, httprequest, razor-pages

I have a Razor app where most of the Client pages have Http.GetJsonAsync requests in the OnInitializeAsync. I have found that if I navigate between pages fast enough that OperationCancelled Exceptions are thrown. After implementing try catches around the get requests as well as trying to pass a CancellationTokenSource Token to the request and calling Cancel() in the page's DisposeAsync to try and preemptively circumvent the exception I still see the OperationCancelled get thrown. I suspect this is being caused by the client receiving a repsonse from the server after the page has been navigated away from and disposed.
Here is what a Client Page looks like:

```
private List<ClassX> list;
private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new();
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync(){
    try{
        list = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<ClassX>>("ServerURL", tokenSource.Token) ?? new();
        tokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
    catch (Exception e) when (e is OperationCanceledException || e is ObjectDisposedException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{e}");
        return;
    }
}

public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    tokenSource.Cancel();
    tokenSource.Dispose()
}
```

My hope with using the CancellationTokenSource was that in calling Cancel in the dispose that even if the exception was thrown, that it would be thrown within the try catch in OnInitializedAsync. From what I have seen in [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cancelable-background-work), this was the correct way to cancel the task and dispose of the token source.

Here is the Console Output:
[Console Output of Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9gP0.png)

I am wondering if the CancellationTokenSource is the correct way to tell the client page that the request no longer matters? Am I implementing the token source correctly, and if so, why is this still throwing an OperationCancelled exception that isn't being caught?

I have tried using the CancellationTokenSource within a using statement but figured that would not work because then the request cannot be canceled when the page begins disposing.

Maybe I am misunderstanding the CancellationTokenSource or how Razor Component Lifecycles work exactly, but I feel like there should be some way to navigate around this problem so that the exception is caught without the user becoming aware from the 'Unhandled Exception' popup in the bottom of the browser window.

Comment: What happens when you remove the  line `tokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` This line does not make much sence because you want to cancel the long running task eg. the http request. The way you are doint it right now is canceling after the request.

Comment: I would have thought this line would throw an OperationCanceledException if token.IsCancellationRequested is true, which is only the case when the page is disposing, and therefore be caught within the try-catch. If removed I'm pretty sure as long as I navigate quick enough between two pages, then an OperationCanceledException will be thrown. I've tested several variations of this, and always seen the exception get thrown and never caught, even with a try catch around the Cancel and Dispose calls.

Comment: Would adding a bool set to true after the request and conditionally canceling be better than outright canceling in the dispose? Since right now, no matter if the long running task returns before we dispose or not, the token will always throw because I am always cancelling when navigating away.

Comment: Update: Removing the ThrowIfCancellationRequested and trying a conditional cancel did not work. I have also tried waiting in the dispose for the initialize to finish before disposing, and that seems to slow down the chance of an OperationCanceledException from being thrown, but it is still thrown eventually. I think this happens because the disposes are backing up behind the scenes.

Comment: i am not able to reproduce. are you missing '@implements IAsyncDisposable' ? Can you share something so we can reproduce this  ?

Comment: @jeb I have the implement statement, everything works as long as the page is given a little time, maybe 1-2+ seconds, but if navigation happens quick enough, sometimes as slow as about 1 second, this series of errors occurs. I'm wondering if it is a similar problem to [This Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74573855/sould-i-catch-operationcanceledexception-in-onparameterssetasync-lifecycle-metho) which seems to have never been answered.

Comment: The only way I am able to reproduce this problem is to use a machine with slower hardware, otherwise my development machine seems to be fast enough to never have it happen.

Comment: Release mode instead of debug might be relevant.